# Finding $x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}$ when given $x=e^t$

Tags: derivatives

The question from my notes involves solving the ODE in the form of:
$$x^2y''+xpy'+qy=r$$

To solve this I set $y=e^t$ and I stated that:
$$x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d} t^2}-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d} t}$$

But when I do this now I get:
$$x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d} t^2}$$

I can't see where I got the extra term from?

Comment: Do you know [Frobenius' method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)

Comment: Yes but I also found my error and solved it by considering y as a function of t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a much more easier way to solve this **[Euler equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation)** is to try potential solutions for the homogeneous part of the solution:

$$y_h(x) = K x^n.$$

When substituted this in your original ODE with $r=0$ it yields:

$$ n(n-1) + p n + q = 0,$$

which is a quadratic equation for $n$. Solving for $n$ you will obtain (if $n_1 \neq n_2$):

$$y(x) = C x^{n_1} + D x^{n_2} + y_p(x),$$

where $C$ and $D$ are constants of integration and $y_p$ is the partircular solution. Since the non-homogenous term, $r$, seems to be constant, $y_p$ is then constant too. Prove that the particular solution is then:

$$y_p = r/q.$$

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: solve first $$x^2y''+xpy'+qy=0$$

by setting $y=e^t$ and derive with respect to $t$.
This will give you the $homogeneous$ solution $y_h$.
Find after that the $particular$ solution by setting your $y_h$ in
$$x^2y''+xpy'+qy=r$$

You will obtain the $particular$ solution $y_p$.

The solution of the differential equation will be

$$y=y_h+y_p$$

Comment: I realised by error, $x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d} t^2}-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d} t}$ is correct and the ODE is $y''+(p-1)y'+qy=r$ which I can easily solve, thanks